# Why Contract State not Persisted in Every Test Sequentially?

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, truffle-test

I have a smart contract in truffle project and want to test it. I have multiple tests sequentially which means contract's state after first test will be needed for the second test.

The problem is, it seems that every test file, the contract's state is revert back to be like when first deployed. How is that even possible? Because when I check from ganache, it seems all the accounts create transaction from the test. Even the address of contract instance is same across test file. How did contract's state not change after all of those transactions?

Here is the example

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract SampleStorage {

    uint256 n;

    mapping(address => bool) private _allowAccess;

    modifier checkAllow {
        require(_allowAccess[msg.sender], "you are not allowed to access this");

        _;
    }

    constructor() {
        _allowAccess[msg.sender] = true;
    }

    function allow(address _user) external checkAllow {
        _allowAccess[_user] = true;
    }

    function setN(uint256 _n) external checkAllow {
        n = _n;
    }

}
```

Here is example of the first test file

```js
const SampleStorage = artifacts.require('SampleStorage');

contract('Grant Access Test', async accounts => {
    it('should grant access to second account', async () => {
        const instance = await SampleStorage.deployed();
        await instance.allow(accounts[1], {from: accounts[0]});
    }
})
```

Here is example of the second test file

```js
const SampleStorage = artifacts.require('SampleStorage');

contract('Change Value Test', async accounts => {
    it('should allow second account to change value', async () => {
        const instance = await SampleStorage.deployed();
        await instance.setN(10, {from: accounts[1]});
        assert.equal(await instance.n(), 10, 'the value is not changed');
    }
})
```

The error is not from the assertion, but from revert back error `"you are not allowed to access this"`.

The weird thing is, transaction from the first account is showed up in ganache.

Comment: The reason this is possible is because ganache seems to redeploy contracts for every test.

Answer (score 1):

This is intended behavior.
Usually when testing we want to revert back after test so we have a clean slate for another test.

If you require the logic/results from the first test for your second test. You might consider joining them in a single "larger" test. Nothing wrong with that.

EDIT: I wrote how I would write the test for your specific case.

```
const SampleStorage = artifacts.require('SampleStorage');

contract('Grant Access Test + Change Value Test ', async accounts => {
    it('should grant access to second account', async () => {
        const instance = await SampleStorage.deployed();
        await instance.allow(accounts[1], {from: accounts[0]});

        //Second part of the Test
        await instance.setN(10, {from: accounts[1]});
        assert.equal(await instance.n(), 10, 'the value is not changed');
    }
})
```

Comment: But, then why there are transactions written in block after testing? How did the blockchain manage to avoid state changing from those transactions? The account balance manage to change from the test but contract state not? This is confusing.

Comment: I don't think Ganache avoids changing states in the blockchain. Rather it's as if he re-deploys all the contracts for each and every test. Thus what was written in the first smartContract during the first test, will not exist in the second SmartContract that is being used for the second test. Even though those two contracts are identical in everything but the address where they are deployed. (At least that is how I understood it)

Comment: The address is still the same across test file. This is the one that I don't understand.

Comment: Yeah I too tried to get the address by using console.log(instance.address),  and it always seems like it's the same contract.

Comment: Weird, right? I don't understand how it works. Even the documentation didn't help much.

Comment: Yeah, something is happening in the background. But we need to take into consideration that Ganache is fine-tuned for testing. For example, I had run tests on public test networks and it often takes up to 10 times longer to finish them. While in Ganache they are done almost instantly (which shouldn't be possible as any action/transaction on a blockchain is dependent on block time). However, it is still very useful for us developers. So I guess this too is one of those things. I don't know what exactly is happening behind curtans but it helps you when writing/running tests.

Comment: This is done using ganache's snapshots.